# What is the difference between a node module and a regular javascript file

Tags: javascript, node.js

Recently I had some experience in writing a very basic Node.js application. But I am a bit confused about the difference between a Node.js module and a JavaScript one. For instance, I can get advantage of the `underscore` library in both Node.js and JavaScript like below:

**Node.js**

```
var _ = require("underscore");
_.each([1, 2, 3], console.log);
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="path/to/underscore.js"></script>
_.each([1, 2, 3], console.log);
```

And I get the exact same result. The point which confuses me is that is it really necessary to have client side coding that runs in browser, while we can handle all of them within a node module?

Comment: You can do all the coding on the server (and it's not node-specific), but if you want to do page manipulations without page refreshing or use AJAX, how are you going to do that without a client-side technology?

Comment: I'm 100% sure that you *don't* get the same result in both cases. If you run `alert()` on the server it will certainly not pop an alert dialog in the client's browser.

Comment: ok `alert` is not important. I mean the same functionality.

Comment: @VsevolodGoloviznin, it is correct about `Ajax`. But I am not sure about the purpose of the existence of some libraries such as `underscore` both as a javascript file and node module

Comment: What do you mean by "same functionality"? If you need something done on the server, you do it on the server. If you need something done on the browser, you do it on the browser. If there's something that can be done on either one, it's your choice to pick which you want to use.

Comment: @Sina the purpose it to use them in node or in the browser. If you want to run the function for an array of elements in the browser what should you do?

Answer (score 1):

Juhanna already said in comments

> If you run alert() on the server it will certainly not pop an alert
>   dialog in the client's browser.

But, if you talk about the functional differences(*and really not concerned about running server code on client: that's foolish*),

> 1: on client side

```
<script src="path/to/xyz.js"></script>
```

script is included in the page, all of it, whatever writtent inside the script, you dont have an option to just import a portion of your xyz.js file.
For example:
xyz.js:

```
var a;
var b;
function Alwaysincluded(){

}
function ThisOnealsoAlwaysincluded(){

}
```

whatever is there in script.js, all the stuff is included in the html file.

> 2: on node server

```
var _ = require("xyz");
```

you can write a whole application and return a just a small object from that , for example if your file contains:

export.js file :

```
var xyz=10;
function neverExported(){
// do some stuff
}
 module.exports = function(width) {
      return {
        area: function() {
          return width * width;
        }
      };
    }
```

what happens here:
the whole file is not exported to the node server, it is executed, then the object which are explicitly exported are delivered.

So in this example `function neverExported()` is never exported to server.js,

**Difference 1: So that one difference between node module and a regular javasript file**

> Now the other one:

**difference 2:**

1: is the script `<script src="path/to/xyz.js"></script>` executed before it is loaded: **NO**

2: is the module `var _ = require("xyz");` executed and then returns an object: **Yes**

So there are two differences here.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure about the first difference. because you can have a javascript module which is written in Revealing pattern and you just return some functionality of that specific module.

Comment: @Sina yes thats true. but in both cases there is a difference: **on client it is  everything being included, you may not reveal**,your choice but still included, **on node it is everything is not included**, your choice to reveal everything... I hope u understand

Comment: If you really want to have variables which are used in a client-side script but not exported, you can do this: `(function() { var x; /* x will not be exported */ /* Do some stuff */ })();`. Here you're defining a function, which contains a local variable `x`, and then running it. The local variable will not be accessible anywhere outside the function definition. `x` can even be a function itself, if you want.

Comment: @NaeemShaikh Your comment is unclear, and in any case it doesn't say how to not export variables from a client-side script.

Comment: @DavidKnipe **on client it is everything being included, you may not reveal**.. you read that

Comment: Usually when people say "you may not..." they mean "you're not allowed to...". That's not what you meant here. Also "your choice but still included" seems to be saying you can either include it or not, but you have to include it, which is contradictory.

Comment: @DavidKnipe no.. the code you have written `(function() { var x; /* x will not be exported */ /* Do some stuff */ })();` will always be included on the client browser, its just that `var x` is not accessible(not revealed and this is your choice to create an anonymous function) , on the other hand on server , what you don't export never ever goes to the server.. i hope you understand though i might have failed to explain in proper english